# SysTick_Handler works as a normal function but not on SysTick interrupt (on QEMU)

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, qemu, rtos

I am trying to implement a simple RTOS with round robin scheduling. Since I do not have a physical board yet, I am running the ELF file on QEMU (qemu-system-gnuarmlinux). For development I am using Eclipse CDT. I use the following command to run the code on QEMU:

```
/opt/xpack-qemu-arm-7.0.0-1/bin/qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse -M STM32F4-Discovery -kernel /mnt/d/eclipse-workspace/rtos/Debug/rtos.elf
```

Each task has an associated struct:

```
struct TCB {
    int32_t *stackPt;
    struct TCB *nextPt;
};
```

At initialization, the structs are chained up in a circular linked list via the `nextPt`, their stacks (`stackPt`) are set as `TCB_STACK[threadNumber][STACK_SIZE-16];` and the stack's program counter is set up as `TCB_STACK[0][STACK_SIZE - 2] = (int32_t)(taskA);`. The current thread's pointer is maintained as: `currentTcbPt`. 
Then the systick is set up to interrupt at every 10ms. An assembly setup function sets up initial stack pointer to the thread stack pointed to by `currentTcbPt`. This function is as follows:

```
osSchedulerLaunch:          // This routine loads up the first thread's stack pointer into SP
    CPSID I
    LDR R0,=currentTcbPt
    LDR R2,[R0]             // R2 = address of current TCB

    LDR SP,[R2]

    POP {R4-R11}
    POP {R0-R3}
    POP {R12}
    ADD SP,SP,#4            // Skip 4 bytes to discard LR
    POP {LR}
    ADD SP,SP,#4            // Skip 4 bytes to discard PSR

    CPSIE I
    BX LR
```

Now, my SysTick_Handler looks like this:

```
__attribute__( ( naked ) ) void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    __asm(
            "CPSID I                    \n"
            "PUSH {R0-R12}              \n"
            "LDR R0,=currentTcbPt       \n"
            "LDR R1,[R0]                \n"
            "STR SP,[R1]                \n"
            "LDR R1,[R1,#4]             \n"
            "STR R1,[R0]                \n"
            "LDR SP,[R1]                \n"
            "POP {R4-R11}               \n"
            "POP {R0-R3}                \n"
            "POP {R12}                  \n"
            "ADD SP,SP,#4               \n"
            "POP {LR}                   \n"
            "ADD SP,SP,#4               \n"
            "CPSIE I                    \n"
            "BX LR                      \n"
            :[currentTcbPt] "=&r" (currentTcbPt)
            );

}
```

I have added extra register operations so I can use it as a normal function.

#### Problem

**First**, I disable interrupts in the `onSchedulerLaunch` function (comment out `CPSIE I`) and in the systick handler. Also renaming `SysTick_Handler` to a random function name (say `Foo`).
Then, I call this `Foo` function at the end of each task (tasks do not have an infinite loop). This works absolutely fine. The tasks get switched over and over as intended.

**Second**, I enable interrupts, set the function's name back to `SysTick_Handler`, re enable interrupts and `extern "C"` and remove the call from the end of tasks. Now, as soon as the SysTick exception happens, the function get's executed, but I get a Usage Fault with a stack register print on terminal.

```
OS init
Launching scheduler
t2
t2
[UsageFault]
Stack frame:
 R0 =  00000003
 R1 =  2000008C
 R2 =  00000000
 R3 =  000004B8
 R12 = 00000000
 LR =  0800148D
 PC =  000004B8
 PSR = 20000000
FSR/FAR:
 CFSR =  00000000
 HFSR =  00000000
 DFSR =  00000000
 AFSR =  00000000
Misc
 LR/EXC_RETURN= FFFFFFF9
```

On examining the asm code using `-d in_asm` option in QEMU and also using remote gdb, The problem seems to happen at the first line of the next task (the same address in `PC` above).

#### Question

What could be the cause of this problem ? Is it perhaps specific to QEMU or is there something wrong with the assembly code ?

EDIT: See the full code to reproduce https://gist.github.com/shivangsgangadia/b78c7c66492d5332c7b4d1806be9c5f6 
The order of execution of function would be something like:

```
RTOS rtos();
rtos.addThreads(&task_a, &task_b, &task_c);
rtos.osKernelLaunch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was setting the T-bit in the Execution PSR register for individual task stacks. The course content that I was following skipped over the fact that the PSR is composed of 4 bytes, and the T-bit in the most significant byte. 
Initially, I was setting it as: `TCB_STACK[threadNumber][STACK_SIZE-1] = (1U << 6);`. This was causing the `BX LR` to not pick up the return address properly.
Setting the 6th bit in the 4th byte, i.e., `TCB_STACK[threadNumber][STACK_SIZE-1] = (1U << 24);` solved the problem and now the scheduler works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Your SysTick_Handler code seems to be scrambling the order of registers. The instruction PUSH {R0-R12} pushes the registers to the stack in the order r0, r1, r2, ... r12, with r0 at the lowest address and r12 at the highest address. But when you execute these instructions in order:

```
        "POP {R4-R11}               \n"
        "POP {R0-R3}                \n"
        "POP {R12}                  \n"
        "ADD SP,SP,#4               \n"
        "POP {LR}                   \n"
        "ADD SP,SP,#4               \n"
```

it will load r4..r11 from the lowest addresses and move SP up. Then it loads r0..r3 from the next 4 addresses, then r12, before skipping one slot and then loading lr and skipping another slot. So you'll not get back to where you were before.

Secondly, this careful setting up of the registers is going to be partially overwritten when the exception handler returns. Arm M-profile exception handlers work by having the CPU push state to the stack on entry and pop it on exception return. (This is done so that in theory you can write an exception handler as a C function, because the stack pushes and pops match the C calling convention for saved registers.) So when you do the "BX LR" at the end of SysTick_Handler() this will cause the hardware to reload R0-R3, R12, PC and the PSR from the stack. If you hadn't changed SP this would be reloading them with the values they had on exception entry; since you have changed SP they'll be pulled from the new stack, and unless you set that bit of the stack up to look like an exception-entry frame this will be garbage. There are also some integrity checks done as part of exception return which you may be falling over if you have set SP to point to something else and not set up that stack correctly.

Finally, disabling interrupts inside the timer interrupt handler looks odd -- the hardware will prevent you from taking an interrupt or exception of same or lower priority as the interrupt handler you're in already.

Overall, I would suggest you read the M-profile architecture manual's description of how M-profile interrupt and exception handling works, because your code looks like maybe you expect it to work like A-profile interrupts where PC is set to the entry point and it's the interrupt handler's responsibility to save and restore all registers.

For debugging this kind of thing I would recommend enabling some of QEMU's '-d' debugging flags. These can be a bit tricky to interpret, but in particular '-d int' will tell you what QEMU is doing in the interrupt entry and exit and why it has decided to raise a UsageFault. (You'll probably want to add some other -d options too, like perhaps 'cpu,exec', to give some context for the int logging.)

Comment: These pop instructions were picked up from the `osSchedulerLaunch` only so that I could use it as a regular function. With or without these, the result / error is the same. Also, I have already tried the `-d` options to figure out at what point was the error occurring as mentioned in the question.

Comment: ...so what do the -d options tell you? If you don't provide a reproducible test case and you don't tell us what the diagnostics say, it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: I used `-d in_asm` and followed the output until I came to the first mention of `[Usage Fault]`. Right before that was the first instruction of the next task. I will add a link to my main ketnel file so you can reproduce it.

Comment: If you actually quote the relevant portion of the logs I could tell you in a bit more detail why it's crashing... The code you link to isn't enough to reproduce -- it's missing how you build it, what the linker map is, etc. But as written it's absolutely not going to work because you change the stack pointer in an exception handler to something that's not a valid exception-handler stack frame and then try to return from it.

Comment: Also, 'in_asm' only traces assembly insns when they are first translated -- you need 'cpu' and/or 'exec' to tell you about actual execution.

Comment: I am actually following https://www.udemy.com/course/c-build-your-own-rtos-from-ground-uptm-on-arm/. How do I share the rest of the project with you ? Should I make a git repo or have a downloadable ZIP ? This seems to be a repo of the code someone else following the course wrote, the code seems to be pretty much the same : https://github.com/dheeptuck/rtos_groundup/tree/master/rtos_groundup/Core/Src

Comment: This is the output from `-d int` 
```
Taking exception 7 [Breakpoint]
...handling as semihosting call 0x4
Taking exception 5 [IRQ]
Taking exception 8 [QEMU v7M exception exit]
Taking exception 5 [IRQ]
Taking exception 8 [QEMU v7M exception exit]
Taking exception 5 [IRQ]
Taking exception 8 [QEMU v7M exception exit]
Taking exception 5 [IRQ]
Taking exception 8 [QEMU v7M exception exit]
Taking exception 1 [Undefined Instruction]
Taking exception 5 [IRQ]
Taking exception 7 [Breakpoint]
...handling as semihosting call 0x4
``` Which one could be the undefined instruction ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245339/discussion-between-shivang-gangadia-and-peter-maydell).